# Why doesn't Javascript (Internet Explorer) show my html table using this function?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I´m using internet explorer 8 and asp.net mvc 3 to develop my web application. I have this code:

```
<div id="table_chart_placeholder">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Table", "Charts"); }
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function chartIndicator() {
        var chartImage = document.getElementById('chart_image');
        chartImage.src = chartImage.src + "?" + new Date().getTime();
        jQuery("#table_chart_placeholder").append("<div></div>").load('@Url.Action("Table", "Charts")');
</script>
```

I can't see the table. Any idea why this happens? If something is not clear please ask me what you need.

Comment: You can't start JavaScript code with the "function" keyword unless it's a function declaration, which it isn't in your case since it lacks a name... I assume you want to invoke that function immediately. In that case, do this: `( function () { ... your code ... })();`

Comment: This function execute when a event triggered, this function have others lines that execute fine, the problem is with internet explorer only, ie don´t show the table, well it show a html element table with thead and tbody but is empty.

Comment: your function is missing it's closing `}` and you say it does not work, because you never actually call chartIndicator();  or do you do that some place else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was caching and I solve it using ajaxSetup in the function like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to do something when the document is ready? you got the document ready function wrong.
try this:

```
<div id="table_chart_placeholder">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Table", "Charts"); }
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
               jQuery("#table_placeholder").append("<div></div>").load('@Url.Action("Table", "Charts")');
              });
</script>
```

Comment: I am sorry I will put the entire code of the fuction

<script type="text/javascript">
     function chartIndicator() {
      var chartImage = document.getElementById('chart_image');
      chartImage.src = chartImage.src + "?" + new Date().getTime();
      jQuery("#table_chart_placeholder").append("<div></div>").load('@Url.Action("Table", "Charts")');
     }
 </script>